# Platformer Starter Kit camera scrolling issue

Tags: c#, matrix, xna, camera, 2d

I'm using the XNA Platformer Kit & I'm trying to implement a camera that follows a player. I followed [David Amador's 2D Camera tutorial](http://www.david-amador.com/2009/10/xna-camera-2d-with-zoom-and-rotation/), and the camera works as expected, it follows the player. But the thing is that all my tiles are not where they should be in the 'Update' method.

The tiles draws correctly on screen, but if I try to click on a tile (I have implemented that if you click a tile with your mouse it breaks & dissapears) nothing happens, *But* if I click on the bottom of the screen (where the tiles where drawn before I implemented the camera, they dissapear as they should. If anyone has had this problem I'd love some help!

(It's like my mouse posistion is not correct when I implemented the camera)

This is from the Player class update method (which is where I have made the changes)

Code:

```
 MouseState mouseState = Mouse.GetState();
   int cellX = (int)(camera.Pos.X + mouseState.X) / Tile.Width;
   int cellY = (int)(camera.Pos.Y + mouseState.Y) / Tile.Height;
   if (cellX < Level.Width && cellX >= 0 && cellY < Level.Height && cellY >= 0)
   {
       if (Level.GetTileAt(cellX, cellY).Collision != TileCollision.Passable)
       {
           if (Level.tiles[cellX, cellY].isDead != true)
           {
               selectionHooverRectangle = Level.GetBounds(cellX, cellY);
               drawHooverRectangle = true;
               hooveredVaildTile = true;
           }
           else
           {
               drawHooverRectangle = false;
               hooveredVaildTile = false;
           }
       }
       else
       {
           drawHooverRectangle = false;
           hooveredVaildTile = false;
       }
   } 

   if (cellX < Level.Width && cellX >= 0 && cellY < Level.Height && cellY >= 0)
   {
       if (mouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
       {
           Level.tiles[cellX, cellY].isDead = true;
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need need to add your camera position to your mouse position when you set the tile.

I assume you use something like this to destrory/create tiles, anything with X and Y values will work, so just replace what is neccessary for your methods.

```
Tiles[MouseX / TileSize, MouseY / TileSize] = new Tile(...);
```

Now to add your camera positon, we will need to use the [matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.matrix.aspx) if you want the zoom and rotation to also carry over. Then we just add the translation values.

```
//Get the transformation matrix
Matrix cameraTransform = cam.get_transformation(device /* Send the variable that has your graphic device here */));

//Find the X and Y position by adding the matrix value to the mouse position, and scaling it down by your tile size
float X = (-cameraTransform.Translation.X + MouseX) / TileSize;
float Y = (-cameraTransform.Translation.Y + MouseY) / TileSize;

//Do Stuff with the tile
Tiles[(int)X,(int)Y] = new Tile(...);
```

Alternatively, If you don't care about the rotation and zoom, You can just add the camera position without the matrix

```
float X = (cam.Position.X + MouseX) / TileSize;
float Y = (cam.Position.Y + MouseY) / TileSize;

//Do Stuff with the tile
Tiles[(int)X,(int)Y] = new Tile(...);
```

Comment: That does not seem to work, they don't dissapear if i click on them & even if i click on the bottom of the screen (where the tiles where before implementing the camera) they doesn't dissapear. This is my code:
        MouseState mouseState = Mouse.GetState();
           int cellX = (int)(-cameraTransform.Translation.X + mouseState.X) / Tile.Width;
           int cellY = (int)(-cameraTransform.Translation.Y + mouseState.Y) / Tile.Height;

    if (mouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
               {
                   Level.tiles[cellX, cellY].isDead = true;
               }

Comment: I just tried it out, it works fine for me, unless I apply zoom or rotation, then it starts to get a little weird. Try debugging it to make sure your X and Y values are within reason.

Comment: No, It really doesn't work for me & I have no idea why, in the levels update method the camera's position is set to the player, so the camera follows the player, & In the mouse click on tile thing I tried your code above & it does not work. The mouse cordinates is still really weard and not accurate

Comment: I edited my question so it now has the code where I kill/remove tlies

Or did you need ALL the code? I'll just edit it again if that's the case

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint to check if the code that kills the block is ever hit? Also, does the camera target the CENTER? Meaning the position is the center of the camera? if so you will need to subtract half the viewport

Comment: The code hits as it should it's just that the mouse posistion is weird, and the camera posistion is set to the player's which makes it so the camera target's the center i guess. But I have no idea where to subtract the viewport

Comment: In the same parentheses as the (camera.Pos.Y + mouseState.Y)

Comment: Hmm... Well this is my code:
int cellY = (int)(camera.Pos.Y + mouseState.Y / 300) / Tile.Height;

and that does not work. :(

Comment: Why are you dividing it by 300?

Comment: Because my viewport's height is 600

Comment: No thats not how you should do it, you need to subtract 300 from the FINAL cellX or Y variable

Comment: Like this? int cellY = (int)(camera.Pos.Y + mouseState.Y) / Tile.Height / 300;